# formatting dictionary keys read from pdf

Tags: python, dictionary

how can I convert this dictionary keys to the following

```
original_di={'001': '', '002': '', '3': '24s', '004': '42s', '5': '', '006': '', '007': '', '008': '', '009': '', '010': '', '011': '', '012\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '013': '', '014': '', '015': '', '016': '', '017': '', '018': '', '019': '', '020': '', '021': '', '022': '', '023': '', '024': '', '025': '', '026': '', '027': '', '028': '', '029': '', '030': '', '031': '', '032': '', '033': '', '041': '', '042': '', '043': '', '044': '', '045': '', '046': '', '047': '', '048': '', '049': '', '050': '', '051': '', '052': '', '053': '', '054': '', '055': '', '056\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '035': '', '037': '', '039\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '034': '', '036': '', '038': '', '040\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '057': '', '092': '', '058': '', '059': '', '060': '', '061': '', '062': '', '063\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '064\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '065\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '066': '', '067': '', '068': '', '069': '', '070': '', '071': '', '072': '', '073': '', '074': '', '075': '', '076': '', '077': '', '078': '', '079': '', '080': '', '081': '', '082': '', '083': '', '084': '', '085\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '086': '', '087': '', '088': '', '089\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '090': '', '091': '', '093': '', '094': '', '095': '', '096': '', '097': '', '098': '', '099': '', '100': '', '101': '', '102': '', '103': '', '104': '', '105': '', '106': '', '107': '', '108': '', '109': '', '110': '', '111': '', '112': '', '113': '', '114': '', '115': '', '116': '', '117': '', '118': '', '119': '', '120': '', '121': '', '122': '', '123': '', '124': '', '125': '', '126': '', '127': '', '128': '', '129': '', '130': '', '131': '', '132': '', '133': '', '134': '', '135': '', '136': '', '137': '', '138': '', '139': '', '140': '', '141': '', '142': '', '143': '', '144': '', '145': '87e', '146': '', '147': '', '148': '', '149\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '150\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '151\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '152\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '153\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '154\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '155\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': 'US', '156': ''}
```

some keys have extra `\r` or `\t` and some have keys which aren't 3 digits.

Ideally, the output I want is for all keys to be 3 digits 001, 003,050, 111 (without \r\t)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, [strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) to remove new-line characters & [rjust](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rjust) to fill in the values

```
{k.strip().rjust(3, "0"): v.strip() for k, v in original_di.items()}
```

Answer (score 1):

`for k, v in original_di.items()` - Iterate on dict and `k` contains the keys and `v` contains the values.

`int(k.strip())` - Removing the new-line characters (Eg.: `\n` or `\t`) from key and casting to integer the string.

`"{0:0=3d}".format(x)` - Create a string which contains 3 digits in every case from your integer

`: v.strip()` - Removing the new-line characters (Eg.: `\n` or `\t`) from value.

**Code:**

```
original_di={'001': '', '002': '', '3': '24s', '004': '42s', '5': '', '006': '', '007': '', '008': '', '009': '', '010': '', '011': '', '012\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '013': '', '014': '', '015': '', '016': '', '017': '', '018': '', '019': '', '020': '', '021': '', '022': '', '023': '', '024': '', '025': '', '026': '', '027': '', '028': '', '029': '', '030': '', '031': '', '032': '', '033': '', '041': '', '042': '', '043': '', '044': '', '045': '', '046': '', '047': '', '048': '', '049': '', '050': '', '051': '', '052': '', '053': '', '054': '', '055': '', '056\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '035': '', '037': '', '039\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '034': '', '036': '', '038': '', '040\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '057': '', '092': '', '058': '', '059': '', '060': '', '061': '', '062': '', '063\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '064\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '065\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '066': '', '067': '', '068': '', '069': '', '070': '', '071': '', '072': '', '073': '', '074': '', '075': '', '076': '', '077': '', '078': '', '079': '', '080': '', '081': '', '082': '', '083': '', '084': '', '085\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '086': '', '087': '', '088': '', '089\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '090': '', '091': '', '093': '', '094': '', '095': '', '096': '', '097': '', '098': '', '099': '', '100': '', '101': '', '102': '', '103': '', '104': '', '105': '', '106': '', '107': '', '108': '', '109': '', '110': '', '111': '', '112': '', '113': '', '114': '', '115': '', '116': '', '117': '', '118': '', '119': '', '120': '', '121': '', '122': '', '123': '', '124': '', '125': '', '126': '', '127': '', '128': '', '129': '', '130': '', '131': '', '132': '', '133': '', '134': '', '135': '', '136': '', '137': '', '138': '', '139': '', '140': '', '141': '', '142': '', '143': '', '144': '', '145': '87e', '146': '', '147': '', '148': '', '149\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '150\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '151\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '152\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '153\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '154\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': '', '155\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r': 'US', '156': ''}
print("{}".format({"{0:0=3d}".format(int(k.strip())): v.strip() for k, v in original_di.items()}))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
{'001': '', '002': '', '003': '24s', '004': '42s', '005': '', '006': '', '007': '', '008': '', '009': '', '010': '', '011': '', '012': '', '013': '', '014': '', '015': '', '016': '', '017': '', '018': '', '019': '', '020': '', '021': '', '022': '', '023': '', '024': '', '025': '', '026': '', '027': '', '028': '', '029': '', '030': '', '031': '', '032': '', '033': '', '041': '', '042': '', '043': '', '044': '', '045': '', '046': '', '047': '', '048': '', '049': '', '050': '', '051': '', '052': '', '053': '', '054': '', '055': '', '056': '', '035': '', '037': '', '039': '', '034': '', '036': '', '038': '', '040': '', '057': '', '092': '', '058': '', '059': '', '060': '', '061': '', '062': '', '063': '', '064': '', '065': '', '066': '', '067': '', '068': '', '069': '', '070': '', '071': '', '072': '', '073': '', '074': '', '075': '', '076': '', '077': '', '078': '', '079': '', '080': '', '081': '', '082': '', '083': '', '084': '', '085': '', '086': '', '087': '', '088': '', '089': '', '090': '', '091': '', '093': '', '094': '', '095': '', '096': '', '097': '', '098': '', '099': '', '100': '', '101': '', '102': '', '103': '', '104': '', '105': '', '106': '', '107': '', '108': '', '109': '', '110': '', '111': '', '112': '', '113': '', '114': '', '115': '', '116': '', '117': '', '118': '', '119': '', '120': '', '121': '', '122': '', '123': '', '124': '', '125': '', '126': '', '127': '', '128': '', '129': '', '130': '', '131': '', '132': '', '133': '', '134': '', '135': '', '136': '', '137': '', '138': '', '139': '', '140': '', '141': '', '142': '', '143': '', '144': '', '145': '87e', '146': '', '147': '', '148': '', '149': '', '150': '', '151': '', '152': '', '153': '', '154': '', '155': 'US', '156': ''}
```